# UI Glitches when using pyqt5+qml

Tags: pyqt, qml

I have a windows application written in qml+pyqt5 (and run on a windows 10 tablet).

1. Sometimes after a tap or on page switch, the application's background turning white, while the buttons are still visible and can be clicked - once I click them or on the screen - the white background disappear.
2. Sometimes after a tap or on page switch, there are strange triangles appearing from random places, and disappears on tap or click.

There is no indication of this bugs in the app's logs, and they fixes themselves on tap or click.

I've noticed that it happens more frequently when there is animation in the page - do you think there is a connection between the things?

Do you familiar with the phenomena, and know by any chance what is the root cause of them and how to deal with it?

Comment: Need to know what version of Qt and what operating system. This likely has to do with the graphics rendering which was GL based in Qt 5 and was rebuilt in Qt 6 to be native to the host platform.

Comment: QT5+WINDOWS.

And there is no way to fix it in Qt5? To avoid those glitches?

Comment: @bimBamBom please be more specific when asked about versions: which version of Qt5? Which Windows version?

Comment: If under Windows and Qt 5, then you probably have a video card driver issue of some sort. You'll want to run through this section of the documentation and update/install drivers or switch to ANGLE as appropriate: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers